# Sencha: Is it possible to keep the touch theme instead of Modern theme?

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I'm working on converting my existing sencha touch 2.4 to sencha 6.0.2. Here i thought of loading my application with the old touch theme instead of new modern theme.

Is this possible to include the touch.css instead on current css which is auto generated using sencha cmd.I tried this but all my component ui get collapsed.

Is there any way to omit the modern theme css included in generated css?

Or else i need to create a new theme which resemble same as touch theme?

Its like upgrade the SDK framework without upgrading or changing the UI design of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a new theme which resembles your existing theme.

Your requirement of

> upgrade the SDK framework without upgrading or changing the UI design of the application.

isn't as straightforward as just swapping a few files. Since there are a lot of differences in the way UI elements are tied to the underlying API between Sencha touch and ExtJs Modern Toolkit, I suggest you look [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/upgrades_migrations/modern_upgrade_guide.html) for the upgrade process, and [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/core_concepts/theming.html) for the theming.